# Rails: Rubber EC2 'cap deploy' command not finishing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2

Everytime I run `cap deploy` I run into this error. I have three instances (db01, web01, app01) and the issue seems to be only with the app instance. Here is what is happening:

```
     triggering after callbacks for `deploy:restart'
   * 2013-01-06 12:13:17 executing `rubber:apache:reload'
   * 2013-01-06 12:13:17 executing `rubber:apache:serial_reload'
   * 2013-01-06 12:13:17 executing `rubber:apache:_serial_task_serial_reload_app01'
     triggering before callbacks for `rubber:apache:_serial_task_serial_reload_app01'
   * 2013-01-06 12:13:17 executing `rubber:passenger:serial_remove_from_pool_reload_app01'
   * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: '  bash -l -c 'rm -f /mnt/vlogio-production/releases/*/public/httpchk.txt && sleep 5'"
     servers: ["app01.foo.com"]
     [app01.foo.com] executing command
     command finished in 10646ms
   * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: '  bash -l -c 'if ! ps ax | grep -v grep | grep -c apache2 &> /dev/null; then service apache2 start; else service apache2 reload; fi'"
     servers: ["app01.foo.com"]
     [app01.foo.com] executing command
  ** [out :: app01.foo.com] * Starting web server apache2
  ** [out :: app01.foo.com] 
  ** [out :: app01.foo.com] 
  ** [out :: app01.foo.com] 
  ** [out :: app01.foo.com] 
  ** [out :: app01.foo.com] [ OK ]
     command finished in 5817ms
     triggering after callbacks for `rubber:apache:_serial_task_serial_reload_app01'
   * 2013-01-06 12:13:34 executing `rubber:passenger:serial_add_to_pool_reload_app01'
  ** Waiting for passenger to startup
   * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: '  bash -l -c 'while ! curl -s -ff http://localhost:$CAPISTRANO:VAR$/ &> /dev/null; do echo .; done'"
     servers: ["app01.foo.com"]
     [app01.foo.com] executing command
  ** [out :: app01.foo.com] .
  ** [out :: app01.foo.com] .
  ** [out :: app01.foo.com] .
  ** [out :: app01.foo.com] .
  ** [out :: app01.foo.com] .
  ** [out :: app01.foo.com] .
  ** [out :: app01.foo.com] .
```

Then `** [out :: app01.foo.com] .` is printed a few times per second indefinitely (I left it 6 hours and nothing happened). Any help fixing this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: Sure thats an error? Looks like you just have to wait to me.

Comment: I'm having this error too. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: @andmcgregor, did you figure this out, and if so, do you remember what you did?

Comment: @n_i_c_k i didn't end up deploying with rubber